# Rotate an object for placement in a 2d array

Tags: java, c#, arrays, rotation, 2d-games

I'm trying to create a basic RTS style grid. The grid works perfectly and I can place object by setting a number to anything other than 0.

That's the easy part. currently im trying to allow each object that is placed to be rotated. The objects that can be rotated can be any size e.g. 1x1, 2x1, 3x4 etc, and all object have an entry block which needs to be rotated with the object.

For example.

My grid is empty

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and I can place an object shown below:

```
1 2 1
1 1 1
```

which will place like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 1 0 0 0       1 2 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 0       1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but when rotated it should place like

```
1 2 1 0 1 1 0     1 2 1   1 1  
1 1 1 0 1 2 0     1 1 1   1 2  
0 0 0 0 1 1 0             1 1  
0 1 1 0 0 0 0       1 1        
0 2 1 0 1 1 1       2 1   1 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 2 1       1 1   1 2 1
```

Im trying to figure out how this could be acheived in code considering that the object can be of different shapes? :(

```
1 1 2 1    1 1 1    1 1 1 1    1 1 1
1 1 1 1    1 1 1    1 1 1 1    2 1 1
1 1 1 1    1 1 2    1 2 1 1    1 1 1
           1 1 1               1 1 1
```

Comment: Start defining constraints: the range of dimensions for the matrix, the range of dimensions for the object, in what position the object must be put inside the matrix at the beginning, rotation means multiple copies of the object (as in your example) or just one? What to do if the object lays in the middle of the matrix? Rotating will cause overlapping...

Comment: And after that, obviously, post your attempt

Comment: Thank for the reply :), Right what the object is is a machine, im creating entry points into the machine so the entry point must be on the outside of the machine. The object will be defined once like the first one I posted.
When I click rotate and click to place the object, it will place it in it's rotated position rather than its defined position.
The size of the object will be defined based on future requests but as of now I wont have it any larger than 4x4.
I still don;t understand how to rotate the object or array :(

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to accomplish this from another board on here.

First thing I did was store the object in a 2 dimensional array e.g.

```
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

I then [transposed](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vmch13/vmch13_14.html) the array leaving me with this array

```
1 1
2 1
1 1
1 1
```

And then I rotated each row leaving me with my final rotated object

```
1 1
1 2
1 1
1 1
```

And for 180+ rotations I just use this technique again to reach the desired rotation :)

My final Array Class in Unity3D C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Arrays {

    public class Array {

        public static int[,] Rotate(int[,] array)
        {
            return Rotate90 (array);
        }

        public static int[,] Rotate90(int[,] array)
        {
            return RotateArrayRow( Transpose(array) );
        }

        public static int[,] Rotate180(int[,] array)
        {
            return Rotate90(Rotate90(array));;
        }

        public static int[,] Rotate270(int[,] array)
        {
            return Rotate90(Rotate180(array));;
        }

        private static int[,] RotateArrayRow(int[,] array){
            int x = array.GetLength(1);
            int y = array.GetLength(0);
            int[,] temp = new int[y,x];
            for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
                {
                    temp[i,x-j-1] = array[i,j];
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public static int[,] Transpose(int[,] array){
            int x = array.GetLength(1);
            int y = array.GetLength(0);
            int[,] temp = new int[x,y];

            for(int i=0; i<y;i++){
                for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
                    temp[j,i] = array[i,j];
                }
            }

            return temp;
        }

        public static void Log(int[,] array){
            for(int i=0; i<array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                string line = "";
                for(int j=0; j<array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    line += array[i,j] + " ";
                }
                Debug.Log(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think about first is that to rotate your objects you only need to implement one rotation function: 90 degrees in one direction. The other rotations just repeat this operation 2 or 3 times, simplifying your logic.

There are two mappings from original to rotated array you need to consider:

1. How do the dimensions map?
2. How do the indices map?

1 is easy: the dimensions are swapped. A rotated 1x4 becomes 4x1.

2 depends on your implementation, but if you're using 2d coordinates `[x, y] => [y, -x] or [-y, x]` depending on direction of rotation.

Comment: I've used this method and got it implemented from another board on here but thanks for the reply :)